# SQLException was unhandled in .net

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm getting this run time exception

> SQLException was unhandled

and the detail is

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

The error is at line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True;");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO patientinfo (patientname, patientid, gender, dob , contactaddress, contactno, doa , referreddoctor, diagnosis, medication, ward) VALUES ('" + patientname + "','" + patientid + "','" + gender + "','" + dtpdob.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + contactaddress + "','" + contactno + "','" + dtpdoa.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + referreddoctor + "','" + diagnosis + "','" + medication + "','" + wardno + "')",con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Details Saved ! ", "PatientInformationSystem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
clearall();
```

Please help

Comment: Sorry for all the mess above i'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: what are the type of each field (schema of patientinfo)? What is the type of each variable that you are using in insert?

Comment: [**SQL Injection alert**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should ***NOT*** concatenate together your SQL statements like this - ***ALWAYS*** use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683

Comment: The error just says that you seem to be trying to insert a `varchar` (string) into a column that's of type `binary`. So which of your columns is of type `binary`?? Make sure to insert a binary value into that column - if you have a string to insert, you need to **CONVERT** it to binary upon insert

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn the basics of proper ADO.NET programming:

- use the `using() { ... }` blocks to ensure proper disposal of disposable items, like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`
- ***NEVER EVER*** concatenate together your SQL statements, but use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection (still the #1 vulnerability on the web!)

So in brief, I would rewrite your code something like this:

```cs
// define your parametrized query
string insertStmt = @"INSERT INTO patientinfo(patientname, patientid, gender, dob, contactaddress, contactno, doa, referreddoctor, diagnosis, medication, ward) 
                      VALUES (@patientname, @patientid, @gender, @dob, @contactaddress, @contactno, @doa, @referreddoctor, @diagnosis, @medication, @ward);"

// define your connection string - typically, you'd read this from a config file
string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True;";

// wrap connection and command in using() blocks
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, con))
{
   // now add and setup the parameter list
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@patientname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = patientname;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@patientid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = patientid;
   ..... and so forth, until *ALL* parameters have been added and defined

   // open connection, execute command, close connection
   con.Open();
   int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```

When doing this, it should become very clear which parameter is of type `binary`, and it should be obvious which string you need to convert to `binary` first, before assigning it to the parameter value.